# C++ add new row in datagrid view table

Tags: datagrid, c++-cli

Using visual studio here. In code below you can see a string being a split, and I want put each split string in a new row, but program crashes not creating a new row and I got error:

> Exception thrown: 'System.ArgumentOutOfRangeException' in mscorlib.dll    Additional information: Index was out of range. Must be non-negative and less than the size of the collection.

```
String^ text = textBox1->Text;
cli::array<String^>^ part = text->Split('.','?','!');
for (int split = 0; split < part->Length; ++split) 
{
    datagrid->Rows[split]->Cells[3]->Value = part[split];
}
```

Comment: Since you didnt give any error message, I guess following questions will drive to the answer..

Where do you initialize variable "split"? Does it have a valid initial value? Why do you have int i and split together in for loop? which one is the index variable? Did you create datagrid and initalize it? Did you allocate enough memory for datagrid->Rows?

Comment: I fix a code and add missing error message.

Comment: so now, you should answer following questions Did you create datagrid and initalize it? Did you allocate enough memory for datagrid->Rows and Cells? as a rule of thumb: always check any pointer before calling its -> operator and always be sure about the size of an array before accesing it with [] operator (error message gives us this hint)

Comment: Datagrid created in using visual studio forms. If split length is 1, then program works fine, but if more than 1, then it crashes not creating a new row. I don't know what else to say. Maybe because it's DataGridViewRow { Index=-1 }

Comment: Or maybe because of error HRESULT : 0x8000000A I get when lunch forms windows for the first time.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You probably don't have enough rows in you data grid so you'll need to add them inside your loop:

```
String^ text = textBox1->Text;
cli::array<String^>^ part = text->Split('.','?','!');

datagrid->Rows->Clear();
for (int split = 0; split < part->Length; ++split) 
{
    datagrid->Rows->Add(part[split]);
}
```